# Issue with adding annotations to iText PDF

Tags: itext

I'm trying to add annotations to a PDF.

I first use **Apache POI** to read an Excel file, and then output to a PDF file. No problems there. When I encounter an error (bad key punched data), I create an annotation and bookmark along with the PDF.

The annotations are my problem. If I just construct:

```
doc.add(new Annotation("Title", "Text");
```

it works fine but the annotation icon is too small.

I'm trying to create a bigger icon. But, It's not creating. I think that it has to do with the float parms I'm giving.

I have used a plethora of:

```
doc.add(new Annotation("Title", "Text", xxxf, xxxf, xxxf, xxxxf));
```

Type statements.

I tried to use the `PDFAnnotation.createText()` but the annotations were never even close to where the bookmarks had them. So, I'm sure I had that wrong also.

I just need to know how to place the annotation.

Comment: I'm downvoting your question because it's too vague in describing the problem you're facing, and you do not provide relevant code or examples someone can use to understand or reproduce your problem.
However, since you're clearly new to iText, I've provided some links to examples and documentation in my answer that can hopefully help you on your way :)

Comment: Sorry, explained the best I could

Answer (score 0):

If you're using iText 7, have a look at the [Jump Start Tutorial](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial), especially [Chapter 4](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/chapter-4-making-pdf-interactive), since it deals with annotations of all kinds.

If you're using iText 5, you can find plenty of examples over [here](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/actions-and-annotations-itext5)